# Starting VM instance 'abc' failed. Error: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM in GCP which was working fine before but today it is giving me "Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1." error .

**Machine type**

n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory).

Any idea how to fix this and

why I am getting this error?

If I am supposed to increase Quota which option to choose from the following?

[image]

Comment: Do you have billing enabled? If yes, request a quota increase for that region. https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota

Comment: yes enabled...but why it was working fine and started giving error now? What's the reason?

Comment: Your quota is 0. You need to request resources in that region. Follow the steps in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: If my CPUs quota is 0, then why was it working fine earlier?

Comment: To answer your edit read this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#vm_instances AND https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#cpus

Comment: I don't know why it was working earlier, you will need to ask Google Cloud Support. Your question does not provide details on your credit standing with Google, account history, etc. I can only guess.

Comment: @JohnHanley.. Can I create a snapshot or image of the existing Standard persistent disk and create a New VM instance with a different zone using that snapshot/image?



Will my all file be copied to the new VM instance then?

Comment: Are you a Free Tier (12-month, $300 free trial) user? If so, has it expired yet?

Comment: Yes, you can create a snaphot in one region and use it in another region. Yes, the entire system with your configuration is saved. This link will help you: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones